# GSON serialization in Kotlin android, override property

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit2

I have a default response class for Retrofit

```
open class DefaultResponseImpl : DefaultResponse {

    override val error: List<RestError>? get() = meta?.listErrors

    @Expose
    var meta: Meta? = null
}
```

and this Meta can have some extra fields, so I want to override it with some extra field like this

```
class SomeResponse : DefaultResponseImpl() {
    @SerializedName("meta")
    @Expose
    val metaLocal: MetaInner? = null

    inner class MetaInner : Meta() {
        @SerializedName("extra_field")
        @Expose
        val field: Long? = null
    }
}
```

but I am getting error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create converter for class com.responses.SomeResponse`

What is wrong? `MetaInner` is subtype of `Meta`, I'm not overriding old meta field with another type (which gives error in IDE). I just add another  field which must be parsed from the same SerializedName

How can this be achieved in Kotlin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it depends on a conflict on "meta" key.
In fact SomeResponse class is equivalent to this class:

```
class SomeResponse : DefaultResponse {

   override val error: List<RestError>? get() = meta?.listErrors

   @Expose
   var meta: Meta? = null

   @SerializedName("meta")
   @Expose
   val metaLocal: MetaInner? = null

   inner class MetaInner : Meta() {
     @SerializedName("extra_field")
     @Expose
     val field: Long? = null
   }
}
```

It's easy to observe that the key *meta* is used for both variables *meta* and *metaLocal*

You could use a unique class for both requests, using generics in order to pass the type of *meta* property.

```
open class DefaultResponseImpl<T> : DefaultResponse {

override val error: List<RestError>? get() {
    if (meta? is Meta?) return meta?.listErrors
    return null
}

@Expose
var meta: T = null
}
```

Comment: Meta is same for all responses, I need some way to extend it when I need to, not to create dozen of same brother-classes which will differ in 1-2 extra fields

Comment: Ok. You could declare meta as private, use a more generic type (JsonObject? JsonArray?) and override the getter.

Comment: Or you could use generics in order to pass the meta property type